# Angular matStepperNext calls unwanted submit method

Tags: angular, mat-stepper

Im using stepper on Angular 11

I want to use 3+ steppers to fill UserData form and evry time i press the `next` button it tries to submit , causing errors and triggering an allert beacouse the form is not completelly filled yet

I made a button `save` to submit data and it's clickable only at the end when the form is valid, but this `next` is ruining my plans

This is the `next` button, not much to see there, just the default one

```
<button mat-button matStepperPrevious>Back</button>
```

How can i keep using `next` button to go from step to step without submitting the form evrytime?

Or how can i make another button that goes to the next step without submitting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add type to button `type="button"`

Comment: By any chances you know why it does the submit if i dont add  ` type button` ?

Comment: I think to perform validations on mat-stepper and is specific to stepper only i'm not so sure about it.

Comment: For me it started showing this behaviour when i moved the stepper into a mat-dialog